# Can't find bad memory indicated by valgrind

Tags: memory-leaks, x86, nasm, valgrind

I'm having trouble with valgrind.
I wrote an assembly program that simulates a game as part of an assignment and I only allocated dynamic memory once for a 2d array called drone_stats. I'm not getting any memory leaks since I did free all memory , but I am getting a bunch of other errors. namely:

> Use of uninitialised value of size 4
> Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation

and they all come from this file:

```
global N
global R
global K
global d
global seed
global drone_stats
global resume
global CORS
global CODEP
global SPP
global seed_dword
global numco
global random
global quit

CODEP equ 0
SPP equ 4

section .rodata         
    format_int: db "%d"
    format_float: db "%f" 

section .bss
    N: resb 4           ; number of drones
    R: resb 4           ; number of rounds per elimination
    K: resb 4           ; number of steps per print
    d: resb 4           ; max distance away from target that allows destruction
    seed: resb 4        ; intial seed for random number

    drone_stats: resb 4 ; pointer to an array of pointer, each pointing the an array of the following format:
                        ; [activated: boolean, id: int, x_pos: float, y_pos: float, speed: float, angle: float, score: int]
                        ; drone_i_arr: [[drone_stats]+ drone_id(i)]
    SPMAIN: resb 4
    SPT: resb 4
    CURR: resb 4
    STKSZ equ 16*1024
    STK1: resb STKSZ
    STK2: resb STKSZ
    STK3: resb STKSZ
    STK4: resb STKSZ

section .data
    
numco:      dd 4
PRINTER:    dd f_printer
            dd STK1+STKSZ
DRONE:      dd f_drone
            dd STK2+STKSZ
TARGET:     dd f_target
            dd STK3+STKSZ
SCHEDULER:  dd f_scheduler
            dd STK4+STKSZ

CORS:       dd PRINTER      ; id 0
            dd DRONE        ; id 1
            dd TARGET       ; id 2
            dd SCHEDULER    ; id 3

temp_macro: dd 4

; macro to free memory allocated by param
%macro      free_array 1
    pushad
    push %1
    call free
    add esp, 4
    popad
%endmacro
; macro to allocate %1 blocks of %2 bytes each , and return a pointer to allocated memory in eax
%macro allocate 2
    pushad 
    push %2
    push %1
    call calloc 
    add esp, 8
    mov [temp_macro], eax
    popad
    mov eax, [temp_macro]
%endmacro
; macro to read an input from the user according to format %2 and store in variable %1
%macro read_formatted 3 ; sscanf(%3, %2, %1)
    pushad
    push dword %1
    push %2
    push %3
    call sscanf
    add esp, 12
    popad                   
%endmacro
; macro to initialize a single co-routine with id %1
%macro init_co 1
    pushad
    mov ebx, %1
    mov ebx, [4*ebx+CORS]
    mov eax, [ebx+CODEP]
    mov [SPT], esp
    mov esp, [ebx+SPP]
    push eax                                ; push into co-routine's stack
    pushfd
    pushad
    mov [ebx+SPP], esp
    mov esp, [SPT]
    popad
%endmacro
;macro to generate a number in range of 0 - %1 and to store it's value in %2
%macro generate_random 2
    push dword %1
    call calc_range
    add esp, 4 
    mov dword [%2], eax 
%endmacro
;============================================================::CODE::================================================================
section .text
    ;funcs
    global main
    extern f_drone
    extern f_printer
    extern f_target
    extern f_scheduler
    extern calc_range
    extern calloc
    extern free
    extern sscanf

    ;vars
    extern target_x
    extern target_y
;================================::AUXILIARY FUNCTIONS::===================================
resume: ; save state of current co-routine
    pushfd
    pushad
    mov edx, dword [CURR]
    mov dword [edx + SPP], esp      ; save current ESP

do_resume:                          ; load ESP for resumed co-routine
    mov esp, dword [ebx + SPP]
    mov dword [CURR], ebx           ; get the current co routine 
    popad                           ; restore resumed co-routine state
    popfd
    ret                             ; "return" to resumed co-routine
;--------------------------------
; void quit()
; function to execute a syscall exit right after freeing all memory allocated by the program
quit:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [drone_stats]
    mov ecx, dword [N]
    .loop:
        mov ebx, [eax]
        free_array ebx

        add eax, 4
    loop .loop

    mov eax, [drone_stats]
    free_array eax

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
;--------------------------------       
; void random()
;
random:
    push ebp                                ; function prologue
    mov ebp, esp    
    pushad 

    mov edx, 16
    seed_loop:
        mov ebx,0
        mov eax,0
        mov ecx,0
        mov bx, word [seed]
        mov cx, 1
        and cx, bx              ; check if the 16 bit is '1' or '0'
        
        shr bx, 2               ; get the 14 bit 
        mov ax, 1
        and ax, bx              ;check the 14 but 
        xor cx, ax 
        
        shr bx, 1               ; get the 13 bit 
        mov ax,1 
        and ax, bx              ; check the 13 bit 
        xor cx, ax 

        shr bx,2                ; get the 11 bit 
        mov ax,1
        and ax, bx              ; check 11 bit
        xor cx , ax 

        mov ax , word [seed]
        shr ax, 1
        shl cx, 15              ; move result to msb 
        or ax, cx   
        
        mov word [seed], ax
        dec edx
        cmp edx ,0
        jne seed_loop

    popad
    mov esp, ebp                            ; function epilogue
    pop ebp
    ret 

main:
    push ebp                                ; function prologue
    mov ebp, esp    
    pushad
    
    ; get command-line arguments: <N> <R> <K> <d> <seed>
    mov ecx , dword [ebp+8]                 ; ecx = argc
    mov ecx, dword [ebp+12]                 ; ecx points to argv[0] = program name
    mov ebx , dword [ecx+4]                 ; ebx is a pointer to N(num_drones)
    read_formatted N, format_int, ebx
    mov ebx , dword [ecx+8]                 ; ebx is a pointer to R(number of rounds before elimination, Round = N steps)
    read_formatted R, format_int, ebx
    mov ebx , dword [ecx+12]                ; ebx is a pointer to K(number of steps before printing the board)
    read_formatted K, format_int, ebx
    mov ebx , dword [ecx+16]                ; ebx is a pointer to d(the maximum distance)
    read_formatted d, format_float, ebx
    mov ebx , dword [ecx+20]                ; ebx is a pointer to seed(LFSR initialization value)
    read_formatted seed, format_int, ebx
    

    ; initialize all co-routines
    mov ecx, [numco]
    xor ebx, ebx                ; id of current co-routine
    .init_cos:
        init_co ebx
        inc ebx
    loop .init_cos

    ; intialize target
    generate_random 100, target_x        ; x: random [0~100]         
    generate_random 100, target_y        ; y: random [0~100]         

    ; allocate an array of pointers. each pointer will point to an array of size 7 that holds all the stats of a single drone:
    ; step1: allocate an array of N (num of drones) pointers
    ; step2: allocate N arrays of size 7 and have each one pointed to by a corresponding pointer in the first array
    allocate dword [N], 4
    mov [drone_stats], eax
    mov ecx, [N]

    mov ebx, [drone_stats]
    .loop_create:
        allocate 7, 4                    ; allocate an array of size 7 to hold the stats of a drone
        mov [ebx], eax                   ; ebx = drone_stats + i*4, that's a pointer to newly allocated memory for each drone 
        add ebx, 4
    loop .loop_create

    ; initialize drones
    mov ecx, dword [N]
    mov edx, dword [drone_stats]
    xor edi, edi
    
    ; initial stats of drone : [mode: on, id: edi, x: random, y: random, speed: random, angle: random, score: 0]
    
    .loop_init:
        mov ebx, [edx]                  ; array of i'th drone

        mov dword [ebx], 1              ; mode: ON
        add ebx, 4
        mov dword [ebx], edi            ; id: edi    
        add ebx, 4
        generate_random 100, ebx        ; x: random [0~100]         
        add ebx, 4
        generate_random 100, ebx        ; y: random [0~100]           
        add ebx, 4 
        
        generate_random 100, ebx        ; speed: random [0~100]           
        add ebx, 4
        generate_random 360, ebx        ; angle: random [0~360] 
        add ebx, 4
        mov dword [ebx], 0              ; score: 0  
        add edx, 4                      ; next drone
        inc edi                         ; next id
    loop .loop_init

    ;; printing the board before playing
    mov ebx, [CORS]
    jmp do_resume
    
    startCo:
        pushad      
        mov [SPMAIN], esp 
        mov ebx, [CORS +12]
        jmp do_resume


    popad           
    mov esp, ebp    
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Can anyone point to the problem? Thanks ahead!

Comment: Doesn't valgrind report an instruction address for the bad usage it's complaining about?  Which instruction does that happen on?

Comment: It does , I just don’t know how to interpret it since I can’t see the addresses of all the instruction in the file. In this case it’s: 0x108CB6 for the use of uninitialized value, and 0x108CAB for the uninitialized value was created by a stack allocation

Comment: If ASLR is a problem, use a debugger and set a breakpoint somewhere near the end, so you can see the message with the address then disassemble to see your instructions and find which ones are at those addresses.

Comment: I tried putting a break point at the startCo label and I'm getting the address 0xef3, which is a lot smaller the address indicated by valgrind I guess. What does that mean ?

Comment: It means you have a PIE executable and you didn't run the program yet, so your debugger is just disassembling the file like objdump would.  Like I said, *run* it first, so those fake addresses (just offsets) get relocated by the kernel and your debugger can see that.  Or better, build this code into a non-PIE executable so addresses are the same every time you run it.

Comment: Well, all I'm getting now is 0x56555ef3, for that same label.. still, I can't see how I can get 0x108CAB/0x108CB6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216544/discussion-between-sadelephent-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: GDB disables ASLR.  You want that (if you have a PIE).  Can you run valgrind inside GDB?  I guess maybe not, I forgot it was valgrind printing the address, not the program itself.  Just build a non-PIE executable with `gcc -m32 -no-pie` to link so addresses will be the same every run, no matter how you run it, so you can match up valgrind output with GDB and objdump.

Comment: I suggest that you use vgdb and single step at the assmbly level.